# CGAffineTransform in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am attempting to call `CGAffineTransformMakeScale` on a `SKLabelNode`. However I receive an error when I try to build the application:

> Property 'transform' not found on object of type 'SKLabelNode *'

Here is my code:

```
self.scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8,0.8);

[UIView beginAnimations:@"button" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
self.scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I'm not exactly sure if this is the correct way to do this using SpriteKit; I had previously used this is an application running off the UIKit. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using SKAction and apply the action to the node.

```
SKAction *a = [SKAction scaleTo: 0.8 duration: 4];
[scoreLabel runAction: a];
```

That will shrink the label over 4 seconds.